# Problem using Ctrl+Arrow keys in Vim when using Byobu with tmux

Tags: tmux, byobu, vim

In Vim, I had set the Ctrl+Arrow keys to skip words. This works just fine when running Vim inside the gnome-terminal.

However, when using [byobu](http://byobu.co/) (tmux), it shows weird behavior : it deletes everything after the cursor.

For reference, these are my vim settings:

```
:inoremap <C-Left> <C-\><C-O>b
:inoremap <C-Right> <C-\><C-O>w
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is twofold.  First, `tmux` by default converts the control-arrow keys from one type of escape sequence to another.  So special keys such as <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> are sent to `vim` without the modifier, e.g., <kbd>left</kbd>.  If you use `cat -v` to see the different escape sequences, you might see something like this

```
^[OD
```

versus this (outside tmux):

```
^[[1;5D
```

The line

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

fixes that aspect.  The other part is that `tmux` by default uses the terminal description for `screen`.  That terminal description does not *describe* the control-arrow keys.  These entries from the terminal database would be the most appropriate for VTE (gnome-terminal):

- [screen.vte](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_vte)
- [screen.vte-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_vte-256color)

There are others, such as

- [screen.xterm-new](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-new)
- [screen.xterm-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-256color)

which would be automatically selected when running in `screen` if the corresponding `TERM` outside were `vte`, `vte-256color`, etc.  `tmux` does not do this automatic-selection; you have to modify its configuration file.

By the way, there is no "screen.xterm" entry because it would interfere with some usages of `screen`.  There is no conflict with `TERM=xterm-new`.

If you have a default (minimal) terminal database such as [`ncurses-base`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/ncurses-base) in Debian, you might not have those.  More common would be [`xterm-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color), which is close enough to use with vim and tmux.

For example, if I add this to my `.tmux.conf` file, it behaves as you expect in vim:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

Further reading:

- [XTERM Extensions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_X_T_E_R_M__Extensions_) (terminal database)
- [vim: how to specify arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542381/vim-how-to-specify-arrow-keys)
- [How can I see what my keyboard sends?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#visible_keys)

Comment: Hmmm... This does work :) But only partially. Only `Control`+`Left` is working; `Control`+`Right` isn't. I'll test and update later.

Comment: You may have some other binding interfering with control+right (given details, I may offer advice).

Comment: Thank you for the offer :) I investigated a bit and found that indeed some other keybindings are causing interference. E.g. on my Mac this works fine, while in Linux (using Guake) it isn't. However, I'm out of station right and can't access my Linux. I will update when I resolve the issue.

Comment: @Thomam Dickey: Meanwhile, I am accepting your answer as it does indeed solve the problem.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'd just like to say, "Go raibh míle maith agat" which in Irish is literally translated as "May you have a thousand good things." Thank you so much for this answer. You're a star.

Answer (score 2):

[From here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144719/how-do-i-get-ctrl-left-ctrl-right-to-jump-a-word-again-in-byobu) you can unbind the key combination in byobu:

Create a file `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` with (or add if the file exists):

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

Then add the following to `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`:

```
unbind-key -n C-Left
unbind-key -n C-Right
```

Comment: This doesn't work. However it has given me solid lead. I'll try to follow the lead and come up with some solution. Thanks :)